# Vectorized meta data computation based on multiple columns on R data.frame

Tags: r, coding-style

I have a data.frame with 3 columns, each of which can be thought of as a factor.  I'd like to compute some stats on the data.frame and store it in a new frame.  To be more specific, I have the following fields:

```
obs, len, src
A    10   X
B    10   Y
```

I'd like to compute the breakdown of each source at each length (i.e. what percentage of observations from source X that are of length 10 are "A", "B", etc.)

An obvious approach to this is to use two for loops to iterate over the lengths and sources and then use nrow() and count() to get the values I'd need to compute, like so:

```
relevant_subset <- data[data$src==source & data$len==length,]
breakdown_info <- count(relevant_subset)
breakdown_info$frac <- breakdown_info$freq / nrow(relevant_subset)
```

Is there a way to avoid using the double for loop and use a more vectorized approach? Is there a smart way to pre-allocate the new frame that would hold the modified breakdown_info for each length and source?

Comment: Have you tried `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `plyr` package was made for!

The format is `<input_type><output_type>ply`. For example if the input is a `data.frame` and you want the output to be a `data.frame` use `ddply`.

To use it, you specify the input `data.frame`, the columns to group by and then a function that constructs a `data.frame` from each group. The resulting `data.frames` appended with the grouping columns are assembled together into the output `data.frame`.

In something similar to your example, you could do

```
require(plyr)
a <- data.frame(
    obs=factor(c('A','A','A','B','B')),
    len=c(10,10,10,10,210),
    src=factor(c('X','X','Y','Y','Z')))
```

then

```
z <- ddply(
  a,
  .(obs),
  function(df){
    data.frame(mean.len=mean(df$len))
  })
```

would produce

```
data.frame(
  obs=c('A', 'B'),
  mean.length(10, 110))
```

while

```
ddply(a, .(src), function(df){
  data.frame(
    num.obs.A = sum(df$obs == 'A'),
    num.obs.B = sum(df$obs == 'B'))})
```

would produce

```
data.frame(
  src=c('X','Y', 'Z'),
  num.obs.A = c(3,1,0),
  num.obs.B = c(0,1,1))
```

The website is http://plyr.had.co.nz/ has good documentation too.

Comment: Thanks, @momeara, this worked for me!  The final form of my code looks like this:

    `ddply(data, .(length, source), function(df){`
        `codes <- levels(df$DSSP)`
        `total <- length(df$DSSP)`
        `foo <- data.frame(x=0)`
        `colnames(foo) <- paste("num.", codes[1], sep="")`
        `for(code in codes) {` 
            `numRes <- sum(df$DSSP == code)`
            `foo[paste("num.", code, sep="")] <- numRes`
            `foo[paste("frac.", code, sep="")] <- numRes / total`
        `}`
        `return(foo)`
    `})`

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` is your friend for these tasks:

Example data:

```
set.seed(23)
test <- data.frame(
  obs=sample(LETTERS[1:2],20,replace=TRUE),
  len=sample(c(10,20),20,replace=TRUE),
  src=sample(LETTERS[24:25],20,replace=TRUE)
)
```

Aggregate it:

```
aggregate(obs ~ src + len,data=test, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))

  src len     obs.A     obs.B
1   X  10 0.6000000 0.4000000
2   Y  10 0.2000000 0.8000000
3   X  20 0.2500000 0.7500000
4   Y  20 0.1666667 0.8333333
```

Comment: `aggregate` could be your enemy here, if you don't know what you're doing or don't view the `str` of your `aggregate` output. For situations such as this, I think that the output for `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(obs ~ src + len,data=test, function(x) prop.table(table(x))))` is more what most people would feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated a reason why you want a data.frame here as output.  Perhaps it's best for you, perhaps not.  You also aren't really clear on what proportions are what but I think the following might solve your problem best.

```
prop.table( table(test) )
```

You could enter it slightly differently and play with the order of columns so that what you want to compare is most easily examined.  But, this output is a 3-dimensional array and quite a bit different from a data.frame.

(example of alternate usage)

```
prop.table(with(test, table(src, obs, len) ))
```